# Android - automatically internet connection when app is close?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-internet

I am creating an app that connect to a `service` and get a notification from service ,I need that when app is close or don't use check internet connection then if connected internet, send my notification to user, I don't like to use a live `thread` in background and check for example per 1 hour I need that whenever internet connected then active my service for notification.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169059/android-event-for-internet-connectivity-state-change

Comment: This link is not my solution .Thanks a lot

Comment: without using bradcast receiver how u will know that internet is connected or not, after get that onreceiver then call your service to check app is opened or not.

Comment: I knew if I did not question.