# How know when a device is connecting to WiFi/Mobile/Internet?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-progressbar

I have button that needs to get some data from a back-end server. The button is disabled while the device is not connected to WiFi/Mobile/Internet. The problem is that when pressing the WiFi button it takes some time till it actually connects (2-3 seconds). How to know when the devices is connecting so I can display a ProgressBar in that periode of time? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android event for internet connectivity state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169059/android-event-for-internet-connectivity-state-change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plenty of methods in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169059/android-event-for-internet-connectivity-state-change) SO question. In short you should use `BroadcastReceiver` with `IntentFilter` with `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` action. Check out `NetworkInfo.State` [DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State) and pick appriopiate for reporting (create own listener with needed callbacks)

if you can afford only [newer APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421930/connectivitymanager-connectivity-action-deprecated) then you can use `NetworkCallback`, in [DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.html) you can see all methods, use appriopiate. But I doubt sadly due to Android fragmentation, still better way is mentioned first one.

Also remember that since Android N this broadcast won't fire when was declared in manifest, use `Java` examples and (un)register with `Activity` lifecycle

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Your answer was very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun isInternetOncheck(context: Context): Boolean {
            val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            val networkInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
            return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
        }
```

```
if (!NetworkCaller.isInternetOncheck(context!!)) {
     println("no internet connection")

} else {

     fetchDataFromServer()
 }
```

```
fetchDataFromServer(){
    showProgressbar()
    ......
    ......
    //code for fetching data
    ......
    ......
    hideProgressbar()
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to always show the `ProgressBar`, I only need to display while the device is connecting (2-3 seconds).